# How can I install Openstack Grizzly using Juju and MAAS?

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, ceph

I've noticed that the new release of Ubuntu 13.04 includes deployment capabilities for Openstack in an HA environment as well as integration of Ceph for volume and object storage. I can't yet find a good walkthrough for it. I'm assuming that this still applies: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure

But are there differences? How many network interfaces should each bare metal server that is in MAAS have?

I am currently using Mirantis' Fuel to deploy Openstack, but it does not yet support Ceph in its automated deployment, which is why I would like to try out Canonical's solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is only a partial answer as this is still a work in progress

The charm work and documentation have not been merged yet, however you can follow along the work-in-progress here:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/OpenStackHA

Comment: Thanks! That link looks great. The only thing is, couldn't some Openstack services be colocated on some of the servers? 28 servers is a lot. Can Juju do that or can it only deploy each service to separate nodes?

Comment: You can virtualize some of them, but if you want full blown openstack it's 28 servers. There will be more detail on how to scale that down over time.

Comment: OK, I understand that info is still coming out on this. I just would really love to deploy Openstack with Ceph and I'm hungry for more docs/info! :)  What if I want to test this on VirtualBox? Or is that the idea of Virtual MAAS?

Comment: Yeah this is the primary use case for virtual maas. The docs should be ready in another week or so!

Comment: If anyone's interested, I'm going to try to use the jitsu principles here to see if I can colocate some of the Openstack services: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuCloudInfrastructure

Comment: No updates still? This question seems interested too http://askubuntu.com/q/346898/169736