# Scaled down Openstack Grizzly installation with Juju and Maas

Tags: server, juju, maas, openstack

I would like to test Openstack Grizzly deployment in the similar way described in [How can I install Openstack Grizzly using Juju and MAAS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/287844/how-can-i-install-openstack-grizzly-using-juju-and-maas) with a limited number of servers, leveraging on Virtual-Maas capability. I was not able finding any documentation and I would appreciate if anybody can share experiences or point me in the right direction.

Thank you,
Luca

Comment: As you can see in Jorge Castro's answer, this is still a "work-in-progress". I saw this entry for [Grizzly](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/OpenStackHA#Cloud_Controller) seems more or less short of documentation.

Comment: Can anybody share their successfull experience if any?

Comment: @LucaDaCol I'm also trying to try out Openstack on top of MaaS using virtual machines. I haven't used the Virtual-Maas stuff, I've just used Maas and set up the VM's that it is running on top of using Libvirt/KVM. Keep getting stuck deploying cinder, nova-cloud-controller, and quantum-gateway

Comment: @LucaDaCol I've made some progress on this, you might try it the local/lxc provider for Juju, it's easy to set up and a lot easier than having to create a lot of VMs and have MaaS manage them. Of course, if you are trying to test MaaS, then using LXC doesn't really get you what you are looking for. But if you are just wanting to test the Juju stuff, it's great (so far with my hour or two of using LXC).

Answer (score 2):

With the latest MAAS and Juju releases (available for 12.04 from the [Cloud Tools archive](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/CloudToolsArchive)), its possible to mix LXC containers with physical servers to support your OpenStack deployment on a smaller number of servers.  Its possible to run the following charms in LXC containers:

- cinder (so long as you are using a Ceph backend)
- glance
- mysql
- rabbitmq-server
- nova-cloud-controller
- swift-proxy
- keystone

Once you have deployed the charms that need physical servers (nova-compute, quantum-gateway, ceph and swift-storage), you can add LXC containers to specific machines:

```
juju add-machine lxc:1
```

The example above will create a LXC container on physical machine 1.

You can then target a charm to a specific LXC container - for example:

```
juju deploy --to 1/lxc/0 nova-cloud-controller
```

Deploys nova-cloud-controller to the first LXC container on physical machine 1.

We have some work currently pending final testing that will allow you to deploy ceph/swift-storage and nova-compute on the same physical machines - allowing you to have shared storage/compute servers within your deployment.